# can we customize Build email in Cruisecontrol.net..?

Tags: cruisecontrol.net

I am having a cruisecontrol.net version 1.5.7256.1 and i integrated  project and unit test and the current behaviour is :

1) if code is checked in successfully and all unit test function passed then email notification is build successfull

2)if code is checked in successfully and any unit test function failed then email notification is build failed

the expected behaviour is if code is checked in successfully and any unit test function failed then email notification should be build passed but unit test failed.

In other words i want to customize the build emails.? is that possible

please help

Thanks,
Nilesh

Hi, I did the changes accordingly i added a condition to check test failed but its not showing while email notification.. is i am forgetting something... ?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it's possible to customize email output by modifying `ccnet.exe.config`.
In this file, XSL sheets are applied to build email.

`dashboard.config` file will customize the web dashboard.

**Usually a successful build means every actions succeed**, from compile to tests and deployment. Maybe you should reconsider the warning only email when test failed.